# How to lock movement on diagonal axis in Vue/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, math, drag

The goal is to lock the movable direction of the div on the diagonal axis.

[image]

**Related to the code below:**

The Event **@mousedown** triggers a boolean to true which activates the move state.

The Event **@mousedown** calculates the offset

The Event **@move** calculates the new coordinates of the div based on the users mouse position

With **e.clientX + (offsetX * Math.tan(angle * rad))** I can lock the movement to a negative gradient.

I tested it with different angels but it looks like the math is wrong.

What am I missing?

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        coordinates: {
            top: "10px",
            left: "10px"
        },
        draggable: false,
        offset: [0, 0],
    },

    methods: {
            down(e) {
            this.draggable = true;
          this.offset = [
            e.target.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
            e.target.offsetTop - e.clientY
          ];
        },
        up(e) {
            this.draggable = false;
        },
        move(e) {
            if (this.draggable) {
              this.coordinates.left = (e.clientX + this.offset[0]) + "px";
              this.coordinates.top = (e.clientX + (this.offset[0] * Math.tan(45 * Math.PI / 180)))  + "px";
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
#app {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

.draggable{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: lightcoral;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app" @mouseup="up" @mousemove="move">
  <div class="draggable" :style="coordinates" @mousedown="down">
    
  </div>
</div>
```